# How to install Python modules in a specific folder and use them in any project with Pycharm or Visual Studio?

Tags: python, module, pycharm, virtualenv

I would like to know if there is any way to install python modules in a specific folder and use these modules (in that specific folder) in any project, to avoid having to install them everytime. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the project requirement its good practice to use separate environment for each project, you can manage project specific environment using Virtual Environments Package of python.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-pip  #installs python package manager
$ sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev  #additional 
$ sudo apt install -y python3-venv #installs pythons Virtual Environments and Packages
$ python3 -m venv my_env  # creates virtual env with name my_env for perticuar project
$ source my_env/bin/activate   # to activate the env
$ deactivate  # to deactivate
```

you can read more here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pip`, the python package manager, you won't have to re-install the modules every time. Read more about pip here: https://pypi.org/project/pip/. To install pip, use

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

then

`python get-pip.py`.

You can replace `python` with `python3` or whatever version you're using.

To install a module, use `pip install <module>`. Then you can import the module in any python program executed with the same version of python pip is installed on using the `import` statement in python.